# How to create new Control depending on SelectedValue in a DropDownList

Tags: asp.net, controls, drop-down-menu

I have a  with dynamic values from an Enum like: String, Int, Double, Bool, DateTime.

How do I create a new Control depending on what is the SelectedValue dynamically into the page? I want a CheckBox for Bool, TextBox for String, Calendar for DateTime etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to do this is to `create` the controls `all together` and `show / hide` the ones required depending on SelectedValue, dynamically.

something like

```
if(someControl.SelectedValue == 1)
{
  Textbox1.Visible = False;
  Textbox2.Visible = True;
}
else  
{
  Textbox1.Visible = True;
  Textbox2.Visible = False;
}
```